# Decimal places float

Tags: c#, floating-point, format, decimalformat

I'm have a hard time trying to format a float with 4 decimal places, for example, I have the number 2.999995, I wanna get only 4 decimal places from this number, 2.9999, when I use .toString("#.####") or .toString("0.0000") it return 2.3000, I don't wanna this, I wanna 2.9999, someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: It's rounding to the number of places you asked for.

Comment: I assume you mean 3.0000?  If you want to show 2.9999, you don't want rounding - search for truncation.

Comment: ok, if I don't wanna round this number, I just wanna get the four decimal places

Comment: that's truncation or Math.Floor

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
float floatVal = 2.999995f;
string str=floatVal.ToString();
if(str.Split('.')[1].Length > 3)
    floatVal=Convert.ToSingle(str.Substring(0,str.IndexOf('.')+5));

Console.WriteLine(floatVal);
```

**Output:**

> 2.9999

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pBmRg6)